# Academic research on technical and philosophical possibilities of the world in a computer simulator?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, simulated-universe

This question is as mainstream as it gets in online publications.

But, does more serious and balanced academic research exist on this subject?

If your PhD student were writing an article on this subject, what would be your recommendation for references?